# Ambiguous error message in Firefox about partitioned attribute in cookie

Tags: firefox, cookies, attributes, partitioned

The error message is:

```
Cookie “blah” will soon be rejected because it is foreign and does not have the “Partitioned“ attribute.
```

but it doesn't say how soon, like in 10 minutes?, next year?, anyone know?